# ObjectDataSource could not find a non-generic method that has parameters:

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, objectdatasource, dataadapter

I'm trying to use a Gridview to show a datatable from an Object data source.  It's giving me the error:

```
ObjectDataSource 'odsStores' could not find a non-generic method 'ProcessDelete' that has parameters: ProcessID.
```

I've read a lot of other answers to this question about matching case, matching format, variables but I think I've done all of those correctly.  Here's the aspx page:

```
                <asp:GridView ID="gridStores" runat="server" AllowSorting="False" AutoGenerateColumns="False"
                    CssClass="grid-main" DataSourceID="odsStores" EnableViewState="False" OnDataBound="gridStores_DataBound"
                    OnRowDataBound="gridStores_RowDataBound">
                    <Columns>
                        <asp:TemplateField ShowHeader="False">
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <asp:Image ID="imgModel" runat="server" AlternateText="Click to See Details" CssClass="img-details"
                                    EnableViewState="False" ImageUrl="~/img/detail.gif" />
                            </ItemTemplate>
                            <ItemStyle CssClass="grid-main-detail" />
                        </asp:TemplateField>
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="ProcessID" HeaderText="ProcessID" />
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="ProcessName" HeaderText="Process Name" ReadOnly="False" />
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="ProcessDescription" HeaderText="Process Description" ReadOnly="False" />
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="UpdateUserID" HeaderText="Last Updated By" ReadOnly="True" />
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="UpdateTimestamp" HeaderText="Last Updated" ReadOnly="True" />
                        <asp:CommandField ShowEditButton="True" />
                        <asp:CommandField ShowDeleteButton="True" />
                    </Columns>
                </asp:GridView>
```

Here's the code behind, all I have is a break point and it never hits it.

```
<DataObjectMethod(DataObjectMethodType.Delete)> _
Private Sub ProcessDelete(ByVal ProcessID As String)
    Dim x As Integer = 0
    x = x + 1
End Sub
```

Here's the object datasource:

```
<asp:ObjectDataSource ID="odsStores" runat="server" EnableViewState="False" OldValuesParameterFormatString="original_{0}"
                    SelectCountMethod="GetRowCount" SelectMethod="GetData" TypeName="DataWarehouseUserInterface.ProcessBSL"
                    UpdateMethod="ProcessUpdate" DeleteMethod="ProcessDelete" >
                    <UpdateParameters>
                        <asp:FormParameter Name="ProcessName" Type="String" FormField="ProcessName" />
                        <asp:FormParameter Name="ProcessDescription" Type="String" FormField="ProcessDescription" />
                    </UpdateParameters>
                    <DeleteParameters>
                        <asp:FormParameter Name="ProcessID" Type="String"/>
                    </DeleteParameters>
                </asp:ObjectDataSource>
```

Comment: Could you post the `<asp:objectdatasource` markup?

Comment: @KarlAnderson, added, sorry I didn't post that initially.

Comment: I am sort of shooting in the dark here, but I was looking at this on MSDN and noticed the `typename` attribute on the `ObjectDataSource` control: typename="Samples.AspNet.CS.EmployeeLogic". Are you omitting the `typename` for any reason and if so when you omit the typename where is the default location that the data source looks for methods?

Comment: @KarlAnderson thanks, I'm impressed you were guessing along the lines of what was wrong without seeing my files :).  Cheers.

Comment: Please show your class file where you have implemented the Methods for ObjectDataSource specially the Delete method.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

My Object data source was looking in my ProcessBSL for a method called ProcessDelete with the corresponding signature.  I had written my methods in the code behind ProcessBSL file.

This was the line of code that effected it:

```
TypeName="DataWarehouseUserInterface.ProcessBSL"
```

Summary:
If it's throwing this error for you, ensure your method signature is correct.  Ensure that the BSL layer is correct.  Make sure you have  _ - that also stopped mine from working.  Hope this helps someone else.

Cheers.

Comment: Answering your own question is awesome.

Comment: The TypeName parameter is very misleading.  I had it set to the Type of object within my IEnumerable.  Thanks for clearing it up gbam!

Answer (score 0):

Try making the method public to see if that works.

Comment: Same error.  It also errors on update as well.  I just assumed it'd be easier to post delete sorry for the initial confusion.